# clone transponder

Tags: car, key, security

Is it possible to clone a 134.2 kHz transponder for a car? I see there are quite [inexpensive projects for readers](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-products-dual-frequency-125khz-134_60568294829.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.36.712420e2UrWQs6), and I was wondering if the encoding is such that the transponder I have for my car could be read and cloned on another [transponder](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/QCONTROL-Vehicle-Transponder-Chip-for-Car-Subaru-4D62-4D-ID62/32849459524.html?spm=2114.search0306.3.16.6ca81de7k6rXIc&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0_10130_453_454_10618_536_10890_317_537_538_319_10059_10696_10084_100031_10083_10547_10546_10887_10307_321_10548_322_10065_10068_10103_10884_10545,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=451f5481-63b2-457f-a71c-ad7abbd482b0&algo_expid=451f5481-63b2-457f-a71c-ad7abbd482b0-1)? I understand from this [datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Texas%20Instruments%20PDFs/RI-TRP-M9WK_Gde.pdf) that when initially purchased they are unlocked, thus could be reprogrammed.

Comment: What vehicle are you looking at? Every manufacturer will do things differently.

Comment: Subaru Outback 2011. It mounts a Transponder Texas Crypto 2 ● ID 4D62-6F ● 6F-62 according to this page https://www.centrochiaviauto.it/tcatalogo/transponder_catalog/subaru_transponder_catalog.html

Comment: The data sheet says that you can't reprogram the car manufacturer ID data in the transponder (for the obvious security reason). You have to buy the chip from the chip manufacturer with that data pre-programmed. You can buy the chips for "non-security-critical" purposes with random manufacturer IDs - but they won't match the ID that Subaru has paid for, of course.

Comment: @alephzero, where is the information about reprogramming that you are quoting please? Section 1.6.1 of the data sheet says that at delivery the password lock is set to 0xFF. When that is changed by to anything other than FF it locks and the chip can't be rewritten. It doesn't say it cannot be read.